# Where does energy for Higgs field come from?

Tags: energy-conservation, standard-model, field-theory, higgs

Yesterday I read that there is a field called Higgs field in space like every other field. But this field has oscillation even without any external energy and reacts to electron with left spins.   Some external source is needed to make waves in EM fields. So there must be some sort of energy needed to make waves in higgs field too. But where does that energy come from. Also space is expanding meaning there is more and more energy needed to make waves in Higgs field (also to make the space itself expand). Are those energy coming from any unknown infinite source.

Comment: I think your last sentence is kinda circular, but AFAIK, the non zero value for the Higgs field is a given, the same as why the electron is the mass it is, there isn't an explanation. I asked a similar question a while back.

Comment: Please  note that in contrast to classical fields, the quantum fields of the particles in the standard model , obeying GFT, do not have energy, the electron field, the muon field etc https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg . They exist all over space similar to coordinate systems. A particle is created with a creation operator  and  annihilated with annihilation operators, described in the feynman diagrams of the interactions. The Higgs field is an underlying coordinate system too.

Answer (score 1):

This question consists of various components.

Firstly, physics rarely has satisfying answers to questions of the kind ‘why does x exist?’. That is more of a philosophical question. Within the Standard Model the Higgs is considered a fundamental field, i.e. not composite. The orthodoxy is that it is a field that has existed since the Big Bang, and that it obtained a non-zero vacuum expectation value after the electro-weak phase transition in the early universe, when the universe’s temperature fell below a critical temperature. This event also coincided with the gauge bosons of the weak force obtaining mass (informally by ‘eating’ three of the four Higgs particles).

I’m not sure I know what exactly an ‘oscillation’ in the Higgs field would be; can you provide a link to the article where you read this? It could mean various things.

From the group theoretical perspective the Higgs is a $SU(2)$ doublet with an associated weak hypercharge. This presumably determines the manner in which it interacts with electrons, but my group theory is rusty.

The impact of an expanding universe is challenging to deal with in the context of QFT, because there is a fundamental tension between the notion of energy in QFT and GR. Searching on this site will lead to useful information. But shortly, there is no need to introduce ‘an unknown infinite source’ of energy.